# CLPFD for real numbers

Tags: constraint-programming, clpfd, approximate

CLP(FD) allows user to set the domain for every wannabe-integer variable, so it's able to solve equations.
So far so good.

However you can't do the same in CLP(R) or similar languages (where you can do only simple inferences). And it's not hard to understand why: the fractional part of a number may have an almost infinite region, putted down by an implementation limit. This mean the search space will be too large to make any practical use for a solver which deals with floats like with integers. So it's the user task to write generator in CLP(R) and set constraint guards where needed to get variables instantiated with numbers (if simple inference is not possible).

So my question here: is there any CLP(FD)-like language over reals? I think it could be implemented by use of number rounding, searching and following incremental approximation.

Comment: Quite spontaneously, I would say that you want [CLP(Q)](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dclpqr.html). That is precise, and the uses are frequently underestimated. Many provers use it.

Comment: Current CLP(FD)-implementation are quite limited in their ability to solve equations. In fact, often it is better to use CLP(Q) and CLP(FD) together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least some major CLP(FD) solvers that support real (decision) variables:

- [Gecode](http://gecode.org)
- [JaCoP](http://jacop.osolpro.com)
- [ECLiPSe CLP](http://eclipseclp.org) ([ic](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic) library)
- [Choco](http://choco.enm.fr) (using [Ibex](http://www.ibex-lib.org))

(The first three also support var float in MiniZinc.)

Answer (score 0):

The answser to your question is yes. There is Constraint-based Solvers dedicated for floating numbers. I do not have a list of solvers but I know that that ibex http://www.ibex-lib.org is a library allowing the use of floats. You should also have a look at SMT-Solvers implementing the Real-Theory (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/solvers.shtml).